# Script only loads after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-refresh

I have a website under construction with an external script from phpjabbers.com, it only loads when I refresh the page. I tried searching for a solution but nothing seems to work. The console in FF didn't give any errors.

The website is http://www.lowie-design.be/test/salon/index.html,
then you can click the menu-button and then 'Verhuur'.
When you go directly to the page http://www.lowie-design.be/test/salon/verhuur.html it works fine.

The script is included on this way within the body where it should appear:

```
<script class="verhuur-script" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.salon-weddings.be/script/index.php?controller=pjFrontEnd&action=pjActionLoad"></script>
```

Everything works fine after I refresh the Verhuur-page.

Comment: Script files should be put on the beginning of the file ideally inside the head tag.

Comment: Check console in Chrome and you'll see few errors there.

Answer (score 0):

Is the second page being loaded by ajax?

When you go straight to the link these scripts are at the bottom

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js">
<script src="js/hammer-v=1.js">
<script src="js/barba.min.js">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js">
<script src="js/MagicScroll.js">
<script src="js/MagicScrollAnimations.min.js">
<script src="js/masonry.js">
<script src="js/main.min-v=1.41.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://salon-weddings.be/script/core/third-party/pj_jquery/1.11.2/pjQuery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://salon-weddings.be/script/core/third-party/pj_validate/1.10.0/pjQuery.validate.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://salon-weddings.be/script/core/third-party/pj_jquery_ui/1.9.2/js/pjQuery-ui.custom.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://salon-weddings.be/script/core/third-party/pj_bootstrap/3.3.2/pjQuery.bootstrap.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://salon-weddings.be/script/app/web/js/pjEquipmentRent.js">
```

When you go via the main menu link, you only get the following at the bottom of the page:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js">
<script src="js/barba.min.js">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js">
<script src="js/MagicScroll.js">
<script src="js/MagicScrollAnimations.min.js">
<script src="js/masonry.js">
<script src="js/main.min-v=1.41.js">
```

And the console app is producing "Hammer is not defined" from line 237 on "main.min-v=1.41.js"

A quick fix would be to add all the possible scripts to the main page so extra pages will look fine on ajax load.

An alternative way would be to make the main menu links an absolute link and make page loading do fancing fading in rather than loading a html page in a specific div.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried with absolute link and to add all the possible scripts to the main page. Nothing worked though.